# Soft keyboard covering EditText Fields android

Tags: android-layout, scroll, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

I have number of Edit Texts in the layout file, the soft keyboard is covering some of the Edit texts. I want whole Edit texts should scroll up if user clicks on first edit text so that all the fields should be visible at a time. I tried adding ScroolView,isScrollContainer,orientation:vertical, requestFocus, android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"  in xml file and  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" is added in Manifest. But not getting expected results.
here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:background="@drawable/register_back"
tools:context="com.example.RegisterActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/registerFieldsRL"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#646b99"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameET"
        android:hint="Enter Your Name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailET"
        android:hint="Enter Your Email Id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameET"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobileET"
        android:hint="Enter Your Mobile Number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailET"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordET"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobileET"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confrm_passwordET"
        android:hint="Re-enter Password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordET"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/logon_button"
        android:text="Logon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/confrm_passwordET"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="#db96a3"
        android:textColor="#e8d3c1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/social_loginsRL"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/social_login_header"
        android:text="- OR LOGIN WITH -"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#646b99"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/social_login_header"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
            android:background="@drawable/fbbutton"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/social_login_split_view"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/social_login_split_view"></View>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gmail_button"
            android:background="@drawable/gmailbutton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/social_login_split_view" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*and here is my Style code*

```
<style name="editTextStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#e8d3c1</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#646b99</item>
</style>
```

*and this is my Drawable file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:drawable="@drawable/patient_details_et_background"/>
     <item>
      <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#d4c6c1" />
         <padding
             android:left="10dp"
             android:top="10dp"
             android:right="10dp"
             android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
     </item>
    </selector>
```

Comment: If you have used `Scroll View` then it should be workable. what is the problem while using it ?

Comment: googlebutton and facebook button are covering the rest of the edittext, only two edittext fields are visible.

Comment: So your all 5 `Edit Texts` isn't scrollable ?

Comment: no.  and and i gave background image, which contains 3 colors, upper part is dark purple, middle is light purple and bottom part is light yellow color and edittext background is also yellow color, so this background image yellow color is mixing with edittext color.

Answer (score 0):

Tara, from what i understand from your question, (maybe i am wrong) that you want all edit text's in your layout to scroll up and be in focus whenever u receive a click on any of the EditText's?

Lets say you have 10 EditText's in your layout, and user clicks the 1st one, if all the EditText's scroll up, the item on which the user clicked also moves from focus. This would not be good for the user, as they wont be able to edit on the actual field on which they clicked.

As for the problem, i would say to put all your EditText's inside a ScrollView and put a attribute, android:fillViewport="true" on the scroll view. This will not solve the problem, but you will be able to see the full length and items inside the scroll view on the preview pane.

The soft keyword will cover some area of the screen once it pop's up, but you should be make sure that the user can scroll across each view in your layout.

Comment: I already added the scroll view and able to scroll also. I have 5 edit text in my layout, requirement is user should able to see all the 5 edit text as there is some space at the top, soft keyboard is covering half part of the last edit text. that's my problem.